# DrawLine offset for corners 

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+

I have a program that allows the user to manipulate a constantly growing line (Tron game), but the problem I am having is that when a player will turn, there is a problem with how the corner appears. For a pen of 1px wide, there is no issue, but when the pen is increased in size, the issue becomes more apparent....

Here is the code:

```
    canvas = this.CreateGraphics();
    foreach (LightBike b in bikes) //draw bikes
    {
        canvas.DrawLine(new Pen(b.color, BIKE_SIZE), b.getPreviousLocation(), b.location);
        grid[b.location.X, b.location.Y] = bikes.IndexOf(b)+1;
    }
```

I store the collisions in a 2D grid that is the size of the from itself. At each position i give a value of the bike in the array.

Seen here at 15px wide:
[image: Tron offset]

Comment: Is this GDI+/Graphics, or is this some actual .NET Canvas library?

Comment: .NET graphics class (I have updated the original post)

Comment: @IanMcCullough - I kind of like the indented corners :)

Comment: Please do not put c# .net in the title. That is what tag are for

Answer (score 1):

This is because the line ends at the point you choose. The fix is easy - just tell the `Pen` to draw a square cap at the start and end of each line:

```
canvas.DrawLine(new Pen(b.color, BIKE_SIZE) {
    EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square,
    StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square
}, b.getPreviousLocation(), b.location);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the **DrawLine** command to draw connected lines. Lines look a lot better if you draw them not one by one in a loop but all in one with the **DrawLines** command.
And: Once you start using an alpha channel even the nicest LineCaps will look really ugly..